# flutter bloc pattren Stream Transformer objects causing syntax errors

Tags: android, dart, flutter, reactive-programming, react-state-management

I am new to **Flutter** and **Dart** language. while following along a tutorial I create a validator class which has 2 **StreamTransformers**, this is being done in an attempt for **bloc** pattren, where user will type email and password in 2 **TextFields** and hence will be validated everytime the text changes in them.

And I am getting bulk of errors specifically in that validator class within the **FromHandler** constructor if I use incoming **email** or **password** they are recognized but when I put them within an **if statement** like I have done here they are not recignized as string objects and that is the cause of error here as you can see in the screenshot below.

[image: validator file errors]

> apart from them **bloc** file also has a couple of errors as shown in 2nd screenshot below:

[image: bloc file errors]

**Flutter version** : 0.5.1
**dart version** : 2.0

> for full code please have a look inside the **login_stateful_bloc** folder in this repo : https://github.com/touseefbsb/LoginStateful

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just remove the => expression and use like this way:

```
    final validateEmail = StreamTransformer<String,String>.fromHandlers(
        handleData: (email,sink) {
          if(email.contains('@')){
            sink.add(email);
          }
          else{
            sink.addError('Email not valid!');
          }
        }
       );
```

The => expr syntax is a shorthand for { return expr; }. The => notation is sometimes referred to as fat arrow syntax.

> Note: Only an expression—not a statement—can appear between the arrow
>   (=>) and the semicolon (;). For example, you can’t put an if statement
>   there, but you can use a conditional expression.

If you want to use => , try something like this:

```
   final validateEmail = StreamTransformer<String,String>.fromHandlers(
      handleData: (email, sink) => _fatArrowMethod(email,sink));

     static _fatArrowMethod(email, sink){
       if(email.contains('@')){
          sink.add(email);
        }
        else{
          sink.addError('Email not valid!');
        }

     }
```

I'm using static on the method because only static methods are accessed from the initializer.

Comment: so in other words, if I have a single line expresion only then should I use fat arrow? but if I have multiple lines then I should just use curly braces? and curcly braces and fat arrow cannot be used together at the same time?

Comment: yep , like u said